# Como solucionar "Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function"

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, modal

Estoy en la creación de una ventana modal la cual requiero que se muestre apenas inicie sesión pero estoy presentando un error en la consola del navegador y es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):25)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

He preparado el siguiente snippet con el codigo que tengo actualmente para mostrar mi ventana modal:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activos/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activos/css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="activos/img/icon.png" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script>

  (function($){
  $('#basicModal')({ show: false});
  $('#basicModal').modal('toggle');
});
  
</script>


</head>
  <body>
    <div class="cuerpo">     
      <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                 
    <div id="content-area"> 
    </div>    
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

No se si sea un problema de versiones de JQuery o del Bootstrap que me muestra este error en la consola del navegador y tampoco me abre la ventana modal.

**Actualización 1:**

He usado el modo habitual

```
(function($){
  $('#basicModal')({ show: false});
  $('#basicModal').show();
});
```

Ahora ya no me muestra errores en la consola del navegador pero sigue sin mostrarme la ventana modal, alguna otra sugerencia ?

**Actualización 2:**

Otra de las sugerencias que me hacen en los comentarios es usar `$('#basicModal').modal('toggle');` ya que a veces no funciona `show();` lo he usado de la siguiente manera pero aun no consigo resultado, alguna otra sugerencia ?

```
(function($){
  $('#basicModal')({ show: false});
  $('#basicModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: no te estaría faltando popper?

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas el modo habitual: `(function($) { //Aquí todo el código jQuery });`? ¿Piensas usar otra librería que también usa `$`?

Comment: según la docs `jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS` fijate si el cdn te provee de la version "bundled" que incluye popper `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Comment: @aloMalbarez Cual seria el cdn de popper según mi versión de JQuery y Bootstrap, puedo intentar agregándolo y ver si funciona

Comment: @A.Cedano He usado el modo habitual que mencionas en tu comentario y ahora ya no genera ningún error en consola pero sigue sin mostrarse mi ventana modal, alguna otra sugerencia ? Puedes verlo en el snippet de mi pregunta inicial

Comment: Hola @JohnDoe has probado así. `$('#basicModal').modal('toggle')` a mi el `show` tampoco me funciona

Comment: @Miguel Acabo de intentarlo pero no funciona, sigo sin resultados, puedes validarlo en la pregunta actualizada.

Comment: Si es de un inicio de sesión, cuando inicia sesión va a otra página o se mantiene en la misma?

Comment: @Miguel Va a otra pagina y esa pagina es `index.php`

Comment: Prueba lo que te propongo @JohnDoe , suerte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado la versión del jQuery por la que yo utilizo y la versión de Bootstrap por la que yo utilizo, además de añadir `$(document).ready(function ()` para que cargue al abrir el DOM.

Yo lo que haría es que si es para cuando inician sesión, guardar una cookie para mostrarlo solo una vez que inician, si ya existe no lo muestras, y si no existe si, pero eso es depende ya de lo que busques.

No se si tienes problemas con cambiar el jQuery o el Bootstrap, pero te propongo esto.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basicModal').modal('toggle');
    });
</script>


</head>
  <body>
    <div class="cuerpo">     
      <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                 
    <div id="content-area"> 
    </div>    
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Si tengo problema al cambiar la versión de Bootstrap ya que adicional tengo muchas mas clases que depende de mi versión actual que es la 3.3.7, hay alguna versión de JQuery que se compatible con mi versión de Bootrstrap ?

Comment: Mira mi respuesta de nuevo, he utilizado tu versión de Bootstrap sin problemas, ya me dices @JohnDoe

Comment: Gracias por actualizar tu respuesta pero ahora estoy obteniendo el siguiente error en la consola del navegador `(index):20 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):20)
    at j (jquery.js:3094)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3206)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3412)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.js:3428)`

Comment: Revisa bien por si te falto algo, además de aquí lo probe en un entorno de desarrollo y funciona bien. No está reconociendo la función, mira que esté cargando el jquery antes de la función @JohnDoe

Comment: Ya lo probé y ahora si me funciona correctamente la ventana modal pero ahora estoy presentando un problema y es que me muestra la ventana modal en todas mis vistas incluyendo la del login donde ingresa el usuario, como puedo hacer que solo me lo muestre en la pagina donde aterriza después de iniciar sesión  ?

Comment: El problema principal esta solucionando, te aconsejo que publiques otra pregunta con tu nuevo problema y estare encantado de ayudarte, asi puedes explicar mas sobre el tema. Si la respuesta a sido valida no olvides marcarla como correcta. Un saludo @JohnDoe

Comment: Así tal cual como lo indica en su ultimo comentario he creado una pregunta mas detallada con mi nuevo error, espero que pueda ser de ayuda la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476826/porque-mi-ventana-modal-se-replica-en-todas-las-vistas). Saludos.